# Program exiting call stack earlier than expected

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a program that seems to be exiting the function call stack earlier than intended. askPersonalInformation() calls  askMealPlanInformation(), which in turn calls askMealInformation(). askMealPlanInformation() is intended to execute n times, and within each of those calls askMealInformation() is intended to execute m times. But for the first askMealPlanInformation() call, askMealInformation() is called m times as expected, but askMealPlanInformation() is called no more after first execution.

In troubleshooting this I've written an inner()/outer() function program that works, but can't see why the full program doesn't work.

Full Program (doesn't work):

```
const readline = require('readline');
const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

var askPersonalInformation = function() {
  var age;
  var gender;
  var weight_lbs;
  var height_inches;
  var activityLevel;
  var numberOfMeals;

  rl.question('Age? ', (answer) => {
    age = answer;
    rl.question ('Gender (Male/Female)? ', (answer) => {
      gender = answer;
      rl.question('Weight (lbs): ', (answer) => {
        weight_lbs = answer;
        rl.question('Height (inches): ', (answer) => {
          height_inches = answer;
          rl.question('Number of meals? ', (answer) => {
            numberOfMeals = answer;
            askMealPlanInformation(0, numberOfMeals);
          })
        });
      });
    });
  });
}

var askMealPlanInformation = function(counter, limit) {
    rl.question("New Meal Name: ", (answer) => {
      rl.question("Meal Size: ", (answer) => {
        askMealInformation(0,3);
        if (counter < limit - 1) {
          askMealPlanInformation(counter + 1, limit);
        } else {
          console.log(counter);
          return;
        }
      })
    });
}

var askMealInformation = function (counter, limit) {
  var mealStatus = "Current Meal Status: {To be included}\r\n\r\n";
  var actionPrompt = "Add, Remove, or Edit Food Entry for Current Meal?\r\nKey\tAction\r\n1\tAdd\r\n2\tEdit\r\n\r\nChoice: ";
  console.log(mealStatus);
  rl.question(actionPrompt, (answer) => {
    rl.question("Select Food Group: ", (answer) => {
      rl.question("Select Food: ", (answer) => {
        rl.question("Select Servings: ", (answer) => {
          if (counter < limit - 1) {
            console.log(counter);
            askMealInformation(counter + 1, limit);
          } else {
            console.log(counter);
            return;
          }
        })
      })
    })
  });
}

askPersonalInformation();
```

Sample Program (works):

```
function outer(counter, limit) {
  console.log("Outer: " + counter);
  inner(0, 3);
  if (counter < limit - 1) {
    outer(counter + 1, limit);
  } else {
    return
  }
}

function inner(counter, limit) {
  if (counter < limit - 1) {
    console.log("\tInner: " + counter);
    inner(counter + 1, limit);
  } else {
    console.log("\tInner: " + counter);
    return;
  }
}

outer(0, 3);
```

Comment: Instead of calling `askMealPlanInformation()` recursively (which probably isn't what you want), why don't you just put it in a for loop, like `rl.question('Number of meals? ', (answer) => {
            numberOfMeals = answer;
            for(let i = 0; i < numberOfMeals; i++){
                askMealPlanInformation();
            }` and then inside of that, call `askMealInformation()` the same way? I guess to an outsider it just seems like the way you are doing this is needlessly complex and doesn't reflect what is *actually* happening, or should happen, which is how code gets weird errors

Comment: Thanks for your response @Katie.Sun The reason (I believe) I can't do a while loop is because each successive call to the rl.question() method overwrites the previous question, and rl.question() is an asynchronous function. I'm thinking as a work-around I'll going to use the readline-sync module available on NPM, at least while I get the asynchronous stuff figured out